Stata code for a novel DiD approach and help with inclusion fixed effects to replicates results of Anton et al. (2023)
I am attempting to replicate the methodology proposed by Anton et al. (2023) https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w30785/w30785.pdf to research the causal impacts of common ownership on CSR performance, however I am facing some issues. In their DiD methodology, they are using the inclusion of incumbent firms' industry competitors as a treatment shock.
They are using a five years after and before event window for each inclusion event. However,
the issue that arises is that for some industries, there are industry competitors entering the index every other year. For instance, Murphy Oil Corporation was added in 2005 and then Helmerich & Payne, Inc. was added in 2006. So how can I ideally capture these as two different inclusion events.
I have attempted to use the logic of a cutoff year which means that for an industry, as newer companies are added into the index the cutoff year changes and that is how i have tried to give values of treat and post for each firm of an industry. However, with the cutoff year logic, from the above exmaple, it changes from 2005 to 2006 in year 2006 and I can't capture the pre-treatment and post-treatment years.
I found their do file but I have been unable to understand how they do the did analysis https://dataverse.harvard.edu/file.xhtml?fileId=6430044&version=2.0&toolType=PREVIEW.
Can anyone please take some time and help me with my code for this? Is the logic of a cutoff year alright?
